# Serialization of numerical values in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, floating-point, jwt

I noticed that https://jwt.io/ outputs the same Base64 string for payloads that contain numerical values written in different notations.
For example, these two payloads result in the same Base64 string:

```
{
  "value": 0.000001
}
{
  "value": 1.0e-6
}
```

Both produce: `eyJ2YWx1ZSI6MC4wMDAwMDF9`
Which after decoding displays as: `{"value":0.000001}`

Where can I find more information about this? I guess there is a specification for this in the form of RFC or something similar. Informal resources on a related subject are also appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how you have created a number. I mean which notation has been used for number literal. The internal representation is IEEE 754. When the serialization happens both values are the same. So the same serialization output is expected.

As of the way number is serialized to a string you can read the [Spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2021/#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring). TLDR it depends on the number of significant digits

```js
console.log(1e-6 === .000001)

console.log(JSON.stringify(1e-6), 1e-6.toString())
console.log(JSON.stringify(1e-7), 1e-7.toString())
```

Comment: Is this output determined by the runtime environment? Since I am using JWT.io inside the browser, that means this output depends on the ecma spec. What happens when I try to use it from somewhere else? Perhaps some other platform renders numbers differently. So the JSON is different. And the content of the JWT token is different - digital signature fails... I guess you see what I am trying to find out.

Comment: "Is this output determined by the runtime environment?" - possibly. "What happens when I try to use it from somewhere else?" well, nothing. You have a token which is a string that contains payload and signature. The signature matches the payload not how you interpret the payload.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Possibly I am not thinking clearly. This is my train of thought:
The issuer must create the hash by using base64UrlEncode of the bytes of the payload.
That means the bytes of the JSON object, which means the bytes of the JSON text.
This text is generated by the issuer's runtime env.
Then my code receives the token in the form of some JSON object, parsed by some JSON lib.
So I don't have the verbatim JSON bytes the server sent me.
I also need to create the hash. My lib is going to generate JSON text for me.
So this text is determined by my runtime env/lib.

Comment: I don't really get your scenario. It seems that you have an idea of something you call a "JSON object". There is no such thing. JSON is a string (period). So your issuer signs a string. When you receive a self contained token you check signature of a string, ensure it is valid and then deserialize the string to your host env objects, structs, array of bytes, whatever... It is not clear which additional "hash" you need to create and why it has to work with the same serialization assuming you normally wouldn't have access to the issuer secret.

Comment: Again thank you for your patience. I am with you about this scenario. I understand that JSON is a string and that a signature is derived from a hash of this string.
(That is the hash I am talking about). Consider this scenario: Server A sends JSON with 0.0000001 to client B. Endpoint on client B consumes this original string and creates say a java JsonObject from it. Now, this JsonObject is passed around to some other component. The original string is garbage collected by now.

Comment: This component in client B serializes this JsonObject and sends it to client C. The component in client B serialized this JSON with a 1e-7 value inside. Client C receives this JSON string with 1e-7 value and checks the signature from Server A which was generated for value 0.0000001. Client C concludes that this JWT is faulty. And it should. But this is a problem :)

Comment: The problem is that Client C receives data from Client B but uses a signature coming from Server A to verify the data. It should either trust Client B (so make Client B to use it's own signature) or consume original token. BTW having access to the signature kinda invalidates the point about that original string is somehow lost. If you keep the signature and header why not keep the entire token.

Comment: I was simplifying things a bit. The entire JWT is JSON. We are passing the token the entire time. The problem is we are not passing the same JSON string the entire time.
Why not? Because we are not handling JSON at the textual level, we typically use it through some kind of abstraction our env provides. Clients are microservices, they are not token issuers, they shouldn't try to forge the token. We only trust server A. This is a very typical use case. We can easily verify the token because we have the public key from server A and use the RS256 signing algorithm.

Comment: Actually, the token is typically transferred in an HTTP header, so it is treated as plaintext. So it can be handled as text, which makes the signature verification process easier :) Thanks for your answer!